An equation related to the $q$-calculus
I'm dealing with a functional equation related to the $q$-calculus. Consider the equation
$$F(qx)-F(x)=f(x)\; :\; x\in D_f,$$
where $f$ is a given real function with the domain $D_f$.
If the series $-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}f(q^jx)$ is convergent for all $x\in D_f$, then it is a solution of the equation. Now,

Are there similar solutions of the equation?

Does always exist a solution of the equation?



As is, it is hard to answer your question in general, apart from "it depends". Actually, it depends on functional space you want to work with for $F$, on the "integrability" of $f$, on the domain $D_f$ (e.g. the solution space is very different for multidimensional cases), on the domain of $q$ (do you consider a real $q$ or only a neighbourhood of $1$, as it is often the case in $q$-calculus), etc.

We assume that $D_f$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ and $q\in\mathbb R$.
In order to justify the functional equation we also assume that $qx\in D_f$ for each $x\in D_f$.
If $q=0$ then the solution exists iff $f(0)=0$. In this case $F(0)$ can be any real number and $F(x)=F(0)-f(x)$ for each $x\in D_f$.
If $q=1$ then the solution exists iff $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in D_f$. In this case $F$ can be any function from $D_f$ to $\mathbb R$.
If $q=-1$ then the solution exists iff the function $f$ is odd. In this case $F|D_{f+}$ can be any function from $D_{f+}=\{x\in D_f:x\ge 0\}$ to $\mathbb R$ and $F(-x)=F(x)+f(x)$ for each $x\in D_{f+}$.
Suppose now that $q\not\in\{-1,0,1\}$. Then the set $D_f$ splits into pairwise disjoint orbits of the form $x\cdot \{q^n:n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\}$ or $x\cdot\{q^n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$, where $x\in D_f$, and we can satisfy the functional equation on each orbit independently.
If the orbit is $x\cdot\{q^n:n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\}$ then $F(x)$ can be any real number and
for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $F(x\cdot q^n)=F(x)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x\cdot q^i)$.
If the orbit is $x\cdot\{q^n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ then $F(x)$ can be any real number and for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $F(x\cdot q^n)=F(x)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x\cdot q^i)$ and
$F(x\cdot q^{-n})=F(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n f(x\cdot q^{-i})$.

Thanks for your answer. How about part 1? Do you have any information about it or know of any useful resources?

@M.H.Hooshmand In my answer are described all solutions of the equation. The idea to satisfy the functional equation on each orbit independently is well-known. Unfortunately, I do not know good references. A bit similar is the following famous idea to solve the Cauchy equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$, where $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Consider $\mathbb R$ as a linear space over the field $\mathbb Q$ and choose any basis $B$ in $\mathbb R$. Let $f_0:B\to\mathbb R$ be any map. Given any $x\in R$, there exists a unique map $\bar x:B\to\mathbb Q$ such that $\bar x(b)=0$ for all but finitely many $b\in B$ and $x=\sum_{b\in B} \bar x(b)\cdot b$. Then put $f(x)=\sum_{b\in B} \bar x(b)\cdot f_0(b)$. So the Cauchy equation has a plenty of solutions. But, as far as I remember, if we impose some restrictions on $f$, such as continuity, local boundedness, measurability etc. then there remain only linear solutions.

Using operator methods, if we denote by $S_q$ the linear operator defined by $S_q f(x) = f(qx)$, then the equation reads
$$
(S_q - \text{Id}) F(x) = f(x).
$$
Inverting the operator and using the geometric series, we recover
$$
F(x) = -\frac1{\text{Id}- S_q} f(x) = -\sum_{j=0}^\infty S_q^j f(x) = -\sum_{j=0}^\infty f(q^jx).
$$
This proof is formal, but I wouldn't expect any other solutions to exists, because in the formal sense the solution is unique. It exists only when the sum converges.


Well, if $F$ is a solution to your equation, then $F + c$ is also a solution.

Your solution has no solution if $f(0) \not= 0$. Indeed, for $x = 0$,
$F(qx) - F(x) = F(0) - F(0) = 0$.



Thanks for your time. By similar solution I mean a solution defined by some functional series (this is a trivial related solution in $q$-calculus). Indeed if $F$ is a solution, then all functions of the form $F+\phi$ are solutions of the equation whenever $\phi(qx)=\phi(x)$.

Also, I forgot to mention the condition $qx\neq 0$ (sorry).
